# Can't connect to WebService from Android

Tags: android, asp.net, ksoap

I'm desperate trying to connect my Android App to a web service in ASP.NET,
I have a local Database and I manage it with SQL Server Management Studio, the web service works perfectly, I can insert rows into the DB but I can´t do it from my android app...
Here's the code:

```
try 
     {

         SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

         request.addProperty("usuario", editText1.getText().toString());
         request.addProperty("pass", editText2.getText().toString());
         request.addProperty("email", editText3.getText().toString());

         SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope =
                    new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.dotNet = true;

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try
        {
            transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            SoapPrimitive resultado_xml;

            resultado_xml = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

            String res = resultado_xml.toString();

            if(res.equals("1"))
                lblLatitud.setText("Insertado OK");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            lblLatitud.setText("Error!");
        }

     }
     finally{}
```

I use the KSOAP driver.

There are no problems with that, the app works but the result is always the same "Error!"...

I am not sure what IP and Port number I have to put in the URL, but I've tested all.

- 10.0.2.2
- localhost

Did this query in sql:    select distinct local_net_address, local_tcp_port from sys.dm_exec_connections where local_net_address is not null

and it gives me 192.168.xxx.x and port number 1488.

I've tested also with port numbers like 1433 and 34462, that is the port number in the web service.

I have no idea what happens...

**Edit:** Logcat
[image]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: Just to be sure, you are using ksoap2-android? Not just ksoap2? Because only ksoap2-android which is a fork of ksoap2 will work on Android.

Comment: I use Ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Comment: Well ok I would look at the sent request and compare it with a working request. There might be some differences. Or you could look at the logcat for errors or warnings. I at least don't see anything really wrong with your code.

Comment: LogCat says "request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol"

Comment: There can be multiple reasons for this exception to occur. Do you have the internet permission in your manifest?

Comment: Are you running your code in an emulator?

Comment: Are you sure you are calling the web service with the correct url?

Comment: Yes, I have Internet permission and I'm running it in an emulator

Comment: Try it on a real phone, this could just be a bug in the emulator. Testing your app on a real phone is always preferable.

Comment: I've tried with many differents URLS and port numbers, but noneone works

Comment: I'm not sure, what IP and port number I have to use? because in the web server adress I get "http://localhost:34462//WebService1.asmx"

Comment: It runs on your pc? Then substitut localhost with the local ip of your pc.

Comment: Yes it runs on my pc, I do "ipconfig" in cmd,  write ip in browser but doesn´t connect... I change "localhost:34462//WebService1.asmx" by "192.168.xxx.x:34462//WebService1.asmx" but... "HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid."

Comment: Well it doesn't matter that it doesn't work on your pc for whatever reason, use an android device, not the emulator, ensure that the device is in the same wifi as your pc. and use the url which contains the local ip of the pc running the web service. Also are you sure you don't need a http:// at the start of your url?

Comment: With htpp:// it doesn´t work either, I'm going to try it on my phone

Comment: No... My phone is connected to the same wifi as my laptop, but it still says "Error!" running it into my phone...

Comment: Well then please edit relevant logcat output into your question.

Comment: Now the logcat doesn't have any output. I've tested all...

Comment: Well do the requests reach the server? If not there must be some kind of error or log on the device. If yes, check the response you get from the server.

Comment: How can I know if request reach the server?

Comment: Multiple ways. You can check the server logs. You can check if the soap call is executed properly on the device and check the response you are getting. I suggest that you debug the soap call step by step and most importantly look at the request being sent and the response you are getting.

Comment: Do you mean debug my application step by step?

Comment: Yes, debug the part of your app where you perform the soap call.

Comment: I do that but he logcat doesn't return anything...

Comment: Debug to the part where you call `transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);` and after that statement has been executed look at the request and response dump inside the `transporte` instance. If necessary you can edit them in your question so I can have a look at them too. I think you need to set `transporte.debug = true` to acutally see the response and request dump but I could be mistaken.

Comment: I've edited with the debug.. And thanks for your time :)

Comment: What information should anyone get from the picture you added? Look inside the `transporte` instance and look at the request and response dump.

Comment: How can I look inside the transporte instance?

Comment: The variable explorer in the top right. Just click on the little arrow to the left of `transporte`.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/l7fEuUV.png?1

Comment: You haven't set debug to true. Set debug to true and like I suggested earlier and the requestDump and responseDump will not be null but contain the xml which is exchanged between the device and the server.

Comment: `transporte.debug = true;`

Comment: transporte.debug = true;
       transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

Comment: but requestdump and responseDump are still null

Comment: But no `Exception` is thrown? Are you sure `transporte.call` has been executed when you look at the requestDump and responseDump?

Comment: I execute the program step by step, when I arrive at the line "transporte.call", the responseDump and requestDump are null, and then when I continue the debug, the "Error!" message is shown on the emulator, and I can't see the variables RequestDump and the rest...

Comment: So the the call is never executed successfully? You could have mentioned that sooner... What do you mean "Error!" is displayed?

Comment: Is an Exception thrown? If yes edit the logcat into your question.

Comment: Oh I see... You don't log the Exception you just eat it. Never do that. This problem could have been solved 8 hours ago...

Comment: Replace this line: `lblLatitud.setText("Error!");` with this: `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: And then run the program again and you will find a log of the `Exception` in your logcat. Then edit it in your question please.

Comment: I have edited with the logcat

Comment: Don't post the logcat as image, just copy the relevant parts and post them as text.

Comment: But there seems to be a TimeoutException at the root of your problem. Most likely the url you use to call the web service is wrong.

Comment: Yes, the URL is the only thing that may be wrong, but I've tested with a lot of URLS and ports and noneone work

Comment: Do you have another computer? Try first to determine the ip and check it by pinging from another computer, then try to reach the web service through another computer. When you figured out the url continue testing on the device. Log also on the server. Log each request and also errors that occur on the server.

Comment: And are you sure the server is up and running and if you wrote the server yourself, are you sure it is working correctly?

Comment: Yes, the server run correctly, I have inserted rows with sql server management studio, and from the web service also, and it works perfectly.

Comment: What is the string for SOAP_ACTION?